# For loop inside for loop works without a curly brackets?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

How does a for loop inside for loop works without a curly braces? As you can see there's two for loops inside while loop first too but they require braces but in the main statement in that nested loop no braces are required?

I am confused on that can anyone explain that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int size=2*n-1;
    int start=0;
    int end=size-1;
    int a[size][size];
    
    while(n != 0)
    {
       for(int i=start; i<=end;i++){
         for(int j=start; j<=end;j++){
           if(i==start || i==end ||  j ==start || j==end)
              a[i][j]=n;
         }
       }
    ++start;
    --end;
    --n;
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
          printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is formatted poorly, which hides what the loops are actually doing:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);

    printf("\n");
}
```

The inner loop doesn't need braces since it's only executing one statement (the `printf` call). However, it's good practice to put all loop bodies and conditional expressions in curly brackets anyway.

Comment: but if i put inner loops in curly brackets it throws an error in output. Without the braces in the inner for loop it works fine.
https://imgur.com/u8l0QDe

Comment: @AmmarAhsan You need to do like for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
} Don't include the printf("\n"); within the inner {}

Answer (score 1):

In c `loops` and `if` statements apply only to next statement if they don't have brackets.

In your example this:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++) {
        printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does a for loop inside for loop works without a curly braces?

The *for* loop syntax in C can be illustrated [as follows](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm):

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) statement
```

Where `statement` can be a single statement (*e.g.,* `printf("%d ", a[i][j]);`) or a [compound statement](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/glossary/compound_statement.html)

> A compound statement consists of none or more statements enclosed
> within a set of braces: {}.